# How to make a net core library with usermanager functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Once again i stumbled across a problem. Well its not realy a problem, its more a thing that i want to learn. I want to start learning class libraries for .net core. First of i created a class library project with the right settings. Now i want to create functions which use for example

applicationusermanager

I have no idea how to access the applicationusermanager from my other project. While i was reading some posts i saw that it has something to do with dependencies. Once again , i dont have a clue if its even possible or how should start.

Lets for example say that i have a library function like this:

```
public static async Task<ApplicationUser> Get_User_Test()
    {
        return await _usermanager.FindByEmailAsync("test@test.com");
    }
```

I want this function to run in my main project. I call this by doing `library.Get_User_Test();` but it fails.

Some good articles or suggestions would be appreciated. I just simply dont know where to start.

I hope you are all doing good and are healthy. Thanks for reading this and i whish you a good day.

Kind regards,

Nick

Comment: Hi, @Nick Glas, here is the official Tutorial of library which is  always best learning  to start. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio

Comment: If you have any problem of this, you can update your question and I will follow up your problem all the time.

Comment: Hey there @Michelle Wang. Thanks for the link to the documentation. I mostly understand whats in there but i dont know how to access the _usermanager or _context in the library. Again thanks for the help

Comment: Hi, Nick Glas, I see what you mean. @Johnathan Le answered your question. You could check.

Answer (score 0):

**UserManager** `provides the APIs for managing user in a persistence store`. It is a bare bone of `ASP.NET Core Identity` to provide all authentication/authorization logic when you work with .NET Core. It is a cross-cutting logic so you don't want to test itself. The only thing you perform Unit Test is your custom `IUserStore` when you choose to integrate Database without `Entity Framework Core` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-custom-storage-providers?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

You can imagine **UserManager** will call each implemented method in your implemented `IUserStore` class. Because it is your custom code, so you should write UT for this.

There is a sample code.

```csharp
public class MongoUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepo;
    public MongoUserStore(IUserRepository userRepo)
    {
        _userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public async Task<User> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

            var user = await _userRepo.GetOneAsync(userId);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return user;
            }

            return null;
        }
}
```

Then you need to write UT for this class

```csharp
public class Test
{
    [Fact]
    public async Task Find_By_Id_Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        // Your mock here
        var mockMongoUserStore = Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        // Act
        var user = await mockMongoUserStore.FindByIdAsync("abc", null);
        // Assert
        Assert.True(user != null);
    }
}
```